# Error loading json in python line by line?

Tags: python, json

Here is my json file format,

```
[{
"name": "",
"official_name_en": "Channel Islands",
"official_name_fr": "Îles Anglo-Normandes",
}, and so on......
```

while loading the above json which is in a file I get this error,

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
```

here is my python code,

```
import json

data = []
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: Maybe one of the properties in the list has actually a single quote instead of a double quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be processing the entire file one line at a time. Why not simply use [`.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=read#io.TextIOBase.read) to get the entire contents at once, then feed that to json?

```
with open('file') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    data = json.loads(contents)
```

Better yet, why not use `json.load()` to pass the readable directly and let it handle the slurping?

```
with open('file') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: did you mean json.loads not json.load?

Comment: No. `loads` reads from a string, while `load` reads from a readable (like a file handle)

Comment: Or, yes. I just saw the error in the content= version. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

`,}` is not allowed in JSON (I guess that's the problem according to the data given).

Comment: , is permitted in json, the sample above cuts off succeeding json content. and it's not ,} it's },

Comment: I mean `,` with `}`, see the format specification at http://www.json.org/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your reading and decoding the file line by line. Any single line in your file (e.g., `"[{"`) is not a valid JSON expression.

Comment: What is the correct way to load the json file to dict?

Comment: Just use `json.load()` from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your individual lines are not valid JSON. For instance, the first line '[{' by itself is not a valid JSON. If your entire file is actually valid JSON and you want individual lines, first load the entire JSON and then browse through the python dictionary.

```
import json

data = json.loads(open('file').read()) # this should be a list
for list_item in data:
    print(list_item['name'])
```

Comment: I want to convert  json to dictionary